# Use table values in a SQL query

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql

I have a below table

```
+------------------------+
| Column1        Column2 |
+------------------------+
|   101          A_TABLE |
|                        |
|   103          B_TABLE |
+------------------------+
```

I want to run a query such that:

```
if my column1 row 1 has 101 then select * from A_TABLE
If my column1 row 2 has 103 then select * from B_TABLE
and so on
```

I would much appreciate your inputs.

Comment: show us what you have tried so far

Comment: There is no concept of "intrinsic" row numbers in SQL... There is no "row 1", "row 2", ... If you want to order you rows, you have to select a column and do an ORDER BY on it. Then you can say "I want the first row", "I want the second row", ...

Comment: does 101 have to be in row 1? what happens if for some reason the rows are the other way around? Or do you just want to check if 101 exists in the table?

Comment: if the column value is 101 then column 2 value will always be A_TABLE same goes for other column values as well

Comment: I have a query to create this temp table what I want is to run only the results of temp table. For eg if I have three rows returned in the table then I need to run 3 select queries combined by Union

Comment: What's the point of the numbers 101 and 103? You just want always to do select * from the table that is in the other column?

Comment: Yes But thought of using  101 and 103 for any conditional statement for returning column 2 value

Comment: @vijaykumar You need to show us some sample output, based on your data (preferrably more sample data).

Comment: Here is the below Query I tried so far

Comment: SET @TABL=(SELECT COLUMN2 FROM #ENT WHERE COLUMN2 = '101')       SELECT * FROM @TABL

Comment: But here I have manually added COLUMN2 as 101 but I want it to be dynamic

Comment: Since the tables has the same structure, you should combine the tables A_table and B_table into 1 table with an extra column containing the column1 value in a new column in the combined column and drop the other tables

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll need to do something like this:

```
declare @SQL varchar(max) = ''

select @SQL = @SQL + 'select * from ' + Column2 + ' union all '
from table1

set @SQL = left(@SQL, len(@SQL) - 10)

exec (@SQL)
```

This will just take all the tables from column2 and create union all clause from that.

Comment: this solution will only work if the tables has the same structure.

Comment: Yes of course, but that was the requirement in the comments "I need to run 3 select queries combined by Union"

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion I have used your query and it works perfectly fine

Answer (score 0):

You can use sql server cursor:

```
DECLARE @column1 VARCHAR(50) 
DECLARE @column2 VARCHAR(50)
DECLARE @sql VARCHAR(250)

DECLARE db_cursor CURSOR FOR  
SELECT Column1, Column2
FROM Your_table 

OPEN db_cursor   
FETCH NEXT FROM db_cursor INTO @Column1, @Column2   

WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0   
BEGIN  
      --dynamic match between columns 
      @sql = 'select * from ' + @Column2  
      EXEC(@sql)
      FETCH NEXT FROM db_cursor INTO @Column1, @Column2   
END   

CLOSE db_cursor   
DEALLOCATE db_cursor
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a while loop:

```
DECLARE     @Max_Value INT ,@Min_Value INT ,@SQL VARCHAR (1000) =''
SELECT @Max_Value = MAX(Column1) , @Min_Value = MIN(Column1) FROM [Your_Table]
WHILE (@Min_Value <= @Max_Value)
BEGIN
    SET @SQL= ( SELECT 'SELECT * FROM '+table_name FROM [Your_Table] WHERE Column1=@Min_Value)
    EXEC(@SQL)  
    SELECT  @Min_Value = MIN(Column1) FROM [Your_Table] WHERE Column1 > @Min_Value
END
```

Answer (score -1):

```
SELECT CASE Column1 WHEN 101 THEN (SELECT * FROM A_Table)
                    WHEN 103 THEN (SELECT * FROM B_Table)
                    ELSE END
FROM table
```

Do A_Table and B_Table contain a key you can join on as that would make this a lot easier?

If so you could simply do

```
SELECT * FROM table T
INNER JOIN A_Table A on T.Column1 = A.Column1
INNER JOIN B_Table B on T.Column1 = B.Column1
WHERE T.Column1 IN (101,103)
```

The second option is best for performance however not sure if this is the output you are after.  Please can you provide the structures of tables A and B and how tables A,B,...,Z link to "table" via any keys?  Also a target results output would be handy.  Thanks!